# How to configure username passed to app when using OpenID auth with OKTA

Tags: openid, okta

I've added an application to Okta using openid to provide authorisation to an apache-hosted site. It works but the REMOTE_USER header is set to [okta-ID]@[okta domain].

How can I get okta to pass the AD samaccountname username, not the ID? Am guessing maybe I have to specify OIDCRemoteUserClaim in the apache config but not sure what I should set it to.

**Update**

Well, I couldn't get the username but I can get the email address from which I can extract the first part. Not sure why I needed to specify both scopes but it wouldn't work without it..

```
OIDCScope "openid email"
OIDCRemoteUserClaim email ^(.*)@
```